# Unable to extract XML node value in ORACLE stored proceedure

Tags: c#, xml, oracle, stored-procedures, guid

I have below object(serilizable)/xml structure. I am trying to extracting Ac number which is GUID, but when I try to compare that with Oracle RAW in stored proceedure, it is failing. Could somebody help me to correct it.

My xml is

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ArrayOfResDet xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <ResDet>
    <Ac>5454454578-5582-410c-a672-5b5454537e0</AccountUID>
    <Res>533-75433</ResNumber>
    <CR/>
    <Status>C</Status>
  </ResDet>
  <ResDet>
    <Ac>585544578-5582-410c-a672-gd565676e0</AccountUID>
    <Res>325-78545</ResNumber>
    <CR/>
    <Status>A</Status>
  </ResDet>
</ArrayOfResDet>`
```

Oracle code block is below, I am passing that XML as CLOB type to ORACLE stored proc and extracting value out of it.

```
 update RES_info
 set SMK = 1
 where accountuid = Ac ;
```

Appreciate the help.

Comment: You need to show how you are attempting to extract the value and also explain how c# is involved.

Comment: Your XML appears to be malformed.  the start tag `<Ac>` does not match the end tag `</AccountUID>`  Same goes for `<Res>` and `</ResNumber>`